# Error while deleting files in InetPub

Tags: powershell

Hi everyone i am using the following code to delete files from inetpub but i am getting the error that some files cannot be deleted because they are being used by another process i am using the following code

```
if ($confirmation -eq 'y') {
get-childitem "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Russia\Admin" -recurse | % {

remove-item $_.FullName -recurse -force

}
get-childitem "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Russia\Tab" -recurse | % {
    if($_.Name -ne 'mediacontent')
    {

        remove-item $_.FullName -recurse -force
    }

}
}
```

using this modified code now but files and folders not getting deleted

```
get-childitem "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Russia\Admin" *.log -recurse | 
sort lastWriteTIme -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 | % {


        remove-item $_.FullName -recurse -force
    }


get-childitem "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Russia\Tab" *.log -recurse | 
sort lastWriteTIme -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 | % {
    if($_.Name -ne 'mediacontent')
    {
        remove-item $_.FullName -recurse -force
    }
```

this is the error which i am getting  "remove-item : Cannot remove item
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Russia\Tablet\mediacontent\Html5Game: The process
access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Russia\Tablet\mediacontent\Html5Game' because it is being used by
process.
At C:\Development\PowerShell Scripts_Scripts\Russia.V2_LOCAL_RestoreFromBackups.ps1:52 char:4
+             remove-item $_.FullName -recurse -force
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\inetpub\wwwr...ntent\Html5Game:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item]
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand "

Comment: They're probably in use by IIS. What happens if you stop the service first then try and delete the files?

Comment: There are no services or anything, they all are dummy folders i am just replicating the production server file structure on to my local machine to get this script working so that we can later use it on production. all i did was copied all the folders from production and paste them in my local intet pub but its not working

Answer (score 0):

As per @arco444's comment, IIS has an opened write handle on the newest log. Try this, it will skip the newest log file though your milage may vary due to `-Recurse` switch:

```powershell
...
get-childitem "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Russia\Tab" -exclude mediacontent -recurse | 
    sort lastWriteTIme -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1 | % {
        remove-item $_.FullName -force -recurse
}
```

Comment: By running the above script i am not getting any error but at the same time my folders are not getting deleted in Inetpub

Comment: Yes, the script will only delete log files(the `*.log` filter). You can try it without the filter and add `-recurse` to `remove-item` statement but as I said - your millage may vary.

Comment: but i would like to delete the folder contents, thats where i am getting error

Comment: i am getting error on media content folder in the above code, but i want to skip media content folder and all of its content and delete the rest of the folder, can you please tell me how can i skip media content folder,

Comment: you can use `-exclude` switch as per my edited answer

Comment: its still not workin, 1 thing which i cannot understand, if the files are locked and are being used by another process how can i go into the folder and delete them with shift + del, but with script i am unable to do that

Comment: If you can do that then the files are not locked. I suggest you investigate and post the error or better yet, start another question because the files are _not_ being used by another process. It could be that you navigated to the dir in question and your powershell window is the one locking it.

Comment: i have modified in question , the error message which i am getting is in question

Comment: You need to figure this out yourself, it is **not** a powershell problem. I suggest you use process explorer(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

its fixed, i just put start-sleep after it deletes the admin folder and than it successfully deletes the tablet and restores the backup, thanks for the help